# prevent html tags and other symbols in plain text json

Tags: php, html, sql, json, wordpress

i'm facing a problem into my json. i'm retrieving *wp-json* data from another website and storing into mysql database. everything is working perfectly. but in the post description - showing something like that:
[see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Cfq.jpg)

may you see `<p> <a> <strong> <blockquote> <script> &mdash;` and more all are not into this post. i want to remove them. but i'm not understanding how i can do this. and what's i need to show you to solve this problems?

i have sql database, php functions for storing json from url, and also have an android app. i don't understanding where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `strip_tags` function ([see reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags)). It removes all html and php tags from a string, as well as any null bytes. Should you want to preserve certain tags down the road, you can pass them in as the second parameter.

```
$stripped_string = strip_tags($original_string);
```

As an aside, I want to point out that if you strip the tags completely, you'll need to re-format the post contents every time you load them from the database. If you want to preserve the formatting but protect yourself from injection attacks, you should look into the `htmlspecialchars` function. It encodes the html tags so that you can safely store the string in your database, and you don't have to reconstruct the formatting on each page load. Simply call `htmlspecialchars_decode` when loading the post content from the database.